# How to resize image for list view

Tags: android

i am loading image and title for list view from webservices text is f9 but image is too big.how to resize it and i want to set text in right side and image in left side in each row of list view .i am using this method  Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true);     but nothing appearing on emulator This is my costant class where i am loading image

```
public static Bitmap loadPhotoBitmap(URL url) {
Bitmap bitmap = null ;
InputStream in = null;
BufferedOutputStream out = null;
BufferedOutputStream bfs = null;

try {
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/photo-tmp.jpg");
bfs = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),8192);

final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, 8192);
copy(in, out);                    
out.flush();
final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();

bfs.write(data, 0, data.length);
bfs.flush();

BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opt);

//System.out.println(resized);
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70,70, true);
    return  resized;
} catch (IOException e) {
// android.util.Log.e("message", "Could not load photo: " + this, e);
System.out.println("Exception while loading image");
} finally {
closeStream(in);
closeStream(out);
closeStream(bfs);
}
System.out.println("returning");
return  bitmap;
}
```

LazyAdapter.class

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

System.out.println("Exception before..");
String strUrl = Constants.vctrImagePath.elementAt(counter).toString();// getting imgurl  
System.out.println("Urls...." + strUrl);
URL url =null;
try {
url = new URL(strUrl);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

Bitmap bitmap = Constants.loadPhotoBitmap(url);
//Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true);


RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);        

TextView text1 = new TextView(mContext);
text1.setText(Constants.vctrCategory.elementAt(counter).toString());
LayoutParams params1 = new       LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
text1.setLayoutParams(params1);
text1.setTextSize(20);
text1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
layout.addView(text1);
ImageView img = new ImageView(mContext);
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layout.addView(img);
counter++;
return layout;
}

private void setContentView(ImageView image) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: ok i have mentioned code above

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opt);
```

Replace that with

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();               
opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opts);
```

Comment: thnkx for suggestion  but expite no image being visible

Comment: you may missing this method

imageView.postinvalidate();

Answer (score 0):

> problem was not in my this bitmapfactory class.i hav resolved my isssue.
>   i just change code in my lazy adapter class.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Constants.DownloadImage(strUrl);
    Bitmap resized=null;
    if(bitmap!=null){
    resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
}else{
    System.out.println(strUrl+ "no image here");
}
```

> before i was resizing image in  my list view.while it will resize in adpter class of list view.